# How do i get two drop down list to be displayed side by side?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, formatting

I've been trying to make two drop down lists to be displayed side by side but can't figure  it out. What CSS element property to set to do this. I have to show it in the following format:

```
[company]     [mobile]
```

instead of

```
[company]

[mobile]
```

There are 3 such pairs. Also the pair of 2 select drop boxes doesn't seem to stick to its division.

```html
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
     body
     {
      background-image:url('gradient1.jpg');
      background-repeat:repeat-x;
     }
     .ex
     {
      margin:auto;
      width:90%;
      padding:10px;
      border:outset;
     }
     select
     {
      display:inline;
      cursor:pointer;
     }
    .ey
     {
      display:inline;
     } 
    .gap
     {
      clear:both;
      margin-bottom:2px;
      }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="ex">
        <form id='dd1.mob1' name='dd1.mob1' method='post' action=' '>   
            <p><label>Select Company</label></p><br/>
            <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd1mob1' id='dd1mob1'>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>" . $options . "
            </select>
        </form>
        <form class="ey" id='dd2.mob1' name='dd2.mob1' method='post' action=''> 
            <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p><br/>
            <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd2mob1' id='dd2mob1'>
                " . $options . "
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ex" class="gap" >
        <form  id='dd1.mob2' name='dd1.mob2' method='post' action=' '>  
            <p><label>Select Company</label></p><br/>
            <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd1mob2' id='dd1mob2'>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>" . $options . "
            </select>
        </form>
        <form class="ey" id='dd2.mob2' name='dd2.mob2' method='post' action=''> 
            <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p><br/>
            <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd2mob2' id='dd2mob2'>
                " . $options . "
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ex" class="gap">
        <form  id='dd1.mob3' name='dd1.mob3' method='post' action=' '>  
            <p><label>Select Company</label></p><br/>
            <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd1mob3' id='dd1mob3'>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>" . $options . "
            </select>
        </form>
        <form class="ey" id='dd2.mob3' name='dd2.mob3' method='post' action=''> 
            <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p><br/>
            <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd2mob3' id='dd2mob3'>
                " . $options . "
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you need form for each select element? use float:left style for block, if you want that was inline, and over blocks with br clear="both" for stop floating

Comment: I would think with that many form elements your going to have a lot of issues with the target css looking how you want.

Comment: @Eugene: i added a .gap class and added to all the div elements, is that what you meant ? i had used seprate forms as the values of the 2nd drop down list is dependent on the value of the 1st.

Comment: Add float:left style for form, and they must be inline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this- **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/czukj/)**

```css
 body
 {
  background-image:url('gradient1.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
 }
 .ex
 {
  margin:auto;
  width:90%;
  padding:10px;
  border:outset;
 }
 select
 {
  display:inline;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
.ey
 {
  display:inline-block;
 } 
form{
    display:inline-block;
}
.gap
 {
  clear:both;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  }
```

```html
 <body>
<div class="ex">
    <form id='dd1.mob1' name='dd1.mob1' method='post' action=' '>   
        <p><label>Select Company</label></p><br/>
        <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd1mob1' id='dd1mob1'>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>" . $options . "
        </select>
    </form>
    <form class="ey" id='dd2.mob1' name='dd2.mob1' method='post' action=''> 
        <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p><br/>
        <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd2mob1' id='dd2mob1'>
            " . $options . "
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ex">
    <form  id='dd1.mob2' name='dd1.mob2' method='post' action=' '>  
        <p><label>Select Company</label></p><br/>
        <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd1mob2' id='dd1mob2'>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>" . $options . "
        </select>
    </form>
    <form class="ey" id='dd2.mob2' name='dd2.mob2' method='post' action=''> 
        <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p><br/>
        <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd2mob2' id='dd2mob2'>
            " . $options . "
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ex">
    <form  id='dd1.mob3' name='dd1.mob3' method='post' action=' '>  
        <p><label>Select Company</label></p><br/>
        <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd1mob3' id='dd1mob3'>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>" . $options . "
        </select>
    </form>
    <form class="ey" id='dd2.mob3' name='dd2.mob3' method='post' action=''> 
        <p><label>Select Mobile</label></p><br/>
        <select onchange=filter.submit() name='dd2mob3' id='dd2mob3'>
            " . $options . "
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
.ey
 {
  display:inline-block;
 } 
form{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See this thread for a good explanation of `display: inline-block;`

[What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block?lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

this displays 2 dropdown list side by side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display:block;">
        <select>
            <option>test1</option>
            <option>test2</option>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option>test1</option>
            <option>test2</option>
       </select>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest CSS fix is to add something like

```
form
 {

     float:left;
 }
```

But you may need to think about restructuring as individual forms isn't often a good idea.

Then in the same way you can use the  elements to position.

Comment: that did bring them side by side but at the same time they all shifted out of their divisions. thanks though clears the initial doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the code given, add the following css

```
.ex, form {
float: left;
}  

label{
    padding: 15px;
}
```

A [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/vT8AL/).

That said, I would still recommend cleaning your code and not using so many forms.