# Select tag to be side by side options tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is it possible to have an option list in two columns? For example that an option has a text that is on the left side and another that is on the right, but in the same row.

Example:

```
+-----select options-----+
    option1     option2
    option3     option4
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Not a native select. Only if you develop one or using a plugin.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424594/how-do-i-get-two-drop-down-list-to-be-displayed-side-by-side)

Comment: I like to use this plugin: [Select2](https://select2.org/) for custom styled selects - other plugins are available: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/select/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do that with a standard `select` but you can simulate it. Below is an example which you can modify according to your needs.

When the `form` is submitted, the selected option is being sent as a hidden `input`.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".selected", function() {
  $(this).next(".options").toggleClass("open");
});

$("body").on("click", ".option", function() {
  var value = $(this).find("span").html();
  $(".selected").html(value);
  $("#sel").val(value);
  $(".options").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 160px;
}

.selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

.options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.options.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="selected">Select an option</div>
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="option"><span>Option 1</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 2</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 3</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>Option 4</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You could use a custom attribute (i.e. `data-value`) to hold the option value so that it doesn't need to be equal to the option text, just like the native select-option behave.