# How to display <li> </li> elements in line

Tags: html, css

Hi i am adding this content to `<li>` tags and it is coming one below the other.But i want it to come in one line like this...

```
    Home  aboutus  contactus  ourservices
```

here is my html

```
<ul class="ddbar" id="ddbar">
<li class="topmenu" menu_id="0" style="padding: 0em 44.0714px;">
<a href="http://localhost" class="baritem">Home</a>
</li><li class="topmenu" menu_id="1" style="padding: 0em 15.0714px;">
<a href="#" class="baritem">Communities</a>
</li><li class="topmenu" menu_id="2" style="padding: 0em 8.57143px;">
<a href="#" class="baritem">Gallery</a>
</li><li class="topmenu" menu_id="3" style="padding: 0em 32.0714px;">
<a href="#" class="baritem">Bash</a>
</li><li class="topmenu" menu_id="4" style="padding: 0em 0.0714286px;">
<a href="#" class="baritem">Videos</a>
</li><li class="topmenu" menu_id="5" style="padding: 0em 18.0714px;">
<a href="#" class="baritem">Services</a>
</li><li class="topmenu" menu_id="6" style="padding: 0em 6.07143px;">
<a href="#" class="baritem">Create account</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: On a side note, try to avoid using the `style` attribute. Your `<li>`s have Classes and IDs, use them.

Comment: Indeed, you don't even need those classes and IDs on the LIs at all, as you can target them via the class/ID on the UL itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have the list element on the same line you have to modify their `display` property.
Also you may want to avoid the rendering of the bullet buttons; in this case you have to set the `list-style` of the root list element to `none`.

```css
ul#ddbar {
  list-style: none;
}

ul#ddbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  
  padding: 4px 10px;
  background-color: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ddbar">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: also use *display:inline-block;
for ie8 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `display: inline-block;` if you want to line up the `li` elements, on the other hand you can also you `float: left;`

If you are interested to re factor your code a bit, you are calling class on each `li` and `a` where you can target these elements like

```
ul.ddbar li {
   /* Styles */
}

ul.ddbar li a {
   /* Styles */
}
```

In this way you don't have to call classes on each element as all the classes are same for each type of element

> Note: As far as this attribute goes `menu_id="2"`, it's an invalid
>   markup, I assume that your code is dynamically generated and you don't have much hold on > it, if you do have, also consider removing the inline styles, also if you are using an id for `ul` element you really don't have to call a class, using`ul#ddbar {}` will give you same results

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C27ZF/) (`inline-block` Example)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/C27ZF/1/) (`float` example)

Answer (score 1):

Give a float left to the LI's:

```
#ddbar li{
           float:left;
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul#ddbar {
    list-style: none;
}
ul#ddbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Live demo can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/6EZaQ/

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this:

**Method 1: Floating the list items**

```
li { float:left; }
```

**Method 2 and 3: Displaying the list items in line with eachother**

```
li { display:inline; }
/* OR, if you want more flexibility: */
li { display:inline-block; }
```

See [this question's most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/1317805) for information about the differences.

**Method 4: Displaying the list as a table**

```
ul { display:table; }
li { display:table-cell; }
```

[**All 4 methods in one JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/cfNvj/).

---

As a side note, a couple of points about your current markup:

```
<li ... menu_id="1" style="padding: 0em 15.0714px;" ...>
```

1. `menu_id` isn't a valid attribute. If you want to use a custom attribute like this, you should use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) - so `data-menuid="0"` would suffice.
2. `0em` is the same as `0`. You don't need to specify the unit when dealing with values of 0.

Comment: Good answer, but it might be good to clarify "flexibility". There are both pluses and minuses to using `inline-block` over `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

I would normally use float: left on the LIs, and sometimes I use display: inline-block instead. But you can also use display: table (though by default this will spread the menu across the page):

```
#ddbar {
    list-style: none;
    display: table;
}

#ddbar li {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding this will serve your purpose:-

```
 #ddbar li {
 float:left; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
#ddbar {
    display:inline-block;
   }
```