# Proper way to layout anchor, image and div

Tags: html, css, image, anchor

I have a outer container, containing two links. They are aligning horizontally. The first one contains a div with background image and the second one is just text. The problem is the whole outer container acts as the first anchor, links to the first url while it is supposed to link nothing. Here's the simplified layout

```
<div id="links-block">          
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><div id="edit-quote-button"></div></a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="preview-pdf-link">Preview the PDF</a>
</div>
```

Here is the example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZZQr/). I am just wonder how to structure this set of elements, to prevent this problem.

Comment: Works good for me in Chrome

Comment: @Cherniv That's weird. I just ckecked all browsers I have, only IE works fine. Chrome and firefox have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this css

```
    a{display:inline-block;vertical-align: top;}
#preview-pdf-link {
float: right;
margin-top: -30px; // remove this line 
color: #999999;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZZQr/4/)**

Comment: It seems to work. But I am just don't understand what this line does actually

Comment: because a is inline block elements and you used to inner div div is a block level elements than i change the a value inline into inline-block element than it's work

Comment: More clearfication http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Answer (score 1):

here is your new html structure

```
 <div id="links-block"> 
  <a class="g-link" href="http://www.google.com"><div id="edit-quote-button"></div></a>
  <a class="y-link" href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="preview-pdf-link">Preview the PDF</a>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

add this css to your css file

```
.g-link{
   display:block;
   float:left;
 }
 .y-link{
   display:block;
  }
 .clear{
   clear:both;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   display:block;
}
```

hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great idea to have a div inside the `a` like that (invalid in pre-HTML5). If you set the `edit-quote-button` div to `display: inline-block` it will work better, though. Then remove the negative top margin on the Yahoo link.