# How to flip the glyphicon icon

Tags: css, icons, flip, glyphicons

Is there any way to flip the glyphicon. I found [Flip an Image](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/) CSS trick, but that does not work for the glyphicon. Please any suggestions

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried?

Comment: Refer this link it works

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604829/rotating-glyphicons-font-awesome-in-bootstrap

Comment: Rotating icons that are use pseudo before/after content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779919/css-rotate-a-pseudo-after-or-before-content

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Like this

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-rotate icon-flipped"></i></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon-flipped {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

**OR**

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#rotated-flipped

Comment: This didn`t work. I am not using fontawesome. I am using glyphicons

Comment: This worked for me and I'm using glyphicons (via twitter bootstrap) too

Comment: You should keep in mind to put the real css property last in the list since this could in some cases cause a render differance: https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

Comment: @jCloud to use this solution with Bootstrap Glyphicons you should do like this: `<a href="#" class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat icon-flipped"></span></a>`. Sorry for coding in the comments, my edits were rejected.

Comment: I tried to apply this to iron-icon (which is icon components for Polymer) and it didn't work!! @falguni-panchal do you have an idea ? inside the component there is an svg icon btw

Answer (score 19):

Using glyphicons managed to make this work like so:

HTML

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" id="my-glyphicon"></span>
```

CSS

```
#my-glyphicon {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
        filter: FlipH;
        -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javiros/r1dtjk8v/) here

Comment: i wish it has more elegant solution via an embedded class. so bootstrap does not have such class to rotate right?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG not that I'm aware of.