# flip icon using css3

Tags: css, flip

I tried to search on stack but could not get exact answer.

There is a paragraph with double quotes.

[Here is my code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/knayK)

I want to flip the second quote as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rikc9.png)

HTML

```
<div class="paraCnt">
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.paraCnt {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff

}
body {
  background: #285fac;
}
.paraCnt:before,
.paraCnt:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 39px;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rikc9.png) -13px -20px no-repeat;
}
.paraCnt:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -50px;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609819/how-to-flip-glyphicon-icon

Comment: Do you really need to flip? You seem to have both the type of quotes in a sprite sort of image. [This](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/GtyKw) should be enough.

Comment: I had added them for reference. Thanks for the reply. It was too simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jkhtn)

CSS changes

```
.paraCnt:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -50px;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); /**Add this**/
  transform: scaleX(-1); /**Add this**/
}
```