# Sweetalert problem checked icon in arabic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, sweetalert

when i use sweetalert in rtl direction, checked icon on sweetalert show problem, like this,..

[image]

large image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR3NO.png)

any solution for this problem.
note: this proble showing in rtl (arabic) just.

```
        delete: function (target, context, datatable) {
        swal.fire({
            title: Lang.trans('delete_modal.title'),
            text: Lang.trans('delete_modal.text'),
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonText: "<i class=\"la la-thumbs-up\"></i>" + Lang.trans('delete_modal.yes'),
            confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger",
            showCancelButton: true,
            cancelButtonText: "<i class=\"la la-thumbs-down\"></i> "  + Lang.trans('delete_modal.no'),
            cancelButtonClass: "btn btn-light btn-elevate",
        }).then(function(result){
            if (result.value) {
                if (context.is('table')) {
                    Ajax.settings(context, {loader: context}).delete(target.data('url'), RequestMethod.GET).complete(function(a,s,d) {
                        if (typeof datatable != 'undefined') {
                            let selected = target.parents('tr');
                            datatable.row(selected).remove();
                            datatable.draw(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Arabic speaker here, but I can't tell what's wrong because your attachment image is so small. Can you possibly post a larger screenshot, or actually articulate what isn't displaying correctly?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR3NO.png

Comment: @nageeb the check success on sweetalert is Upturned, on arabic use sweetalert

Answer (score 0):

See this question: [how to flip glyphicon icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609819/how-to-flip-glyphicon-icon)

Try applying a class like this to success icon, or even it's entire containing div.

```
.flipped {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```