# How to make accessible h1 with logo

Tags: html, css, html-heading

How can I have a logo linked to homepage and also have h1 but invisible

I have layout like this

```
 <header id="pageHeader">
                    <h1>
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
                        <?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </h1>
```

Then I've used the css to for image as background but the logo is not loading, anyone?

```
  header#pageHeader h1 a {
  width:130px;
  height:70px;
  text-indent:-9999px;
  background:url(/pict/logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2010/10/your-logo-is-an-image-not-a-h1/

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Comment: Yes still not working, actually I tried the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing `display:inline-block;`

compare [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vT42M/) with [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/vT42M/1/)

differences highlighted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block), quoted below:

> **inline-block**
>
> This value causes an element to generate an inline-level block container. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.
> **inline**
>
> This value causes an element to generate one or more inline boxes.

---

sorry to explain why this works:

`Inline` means *only take up as much space as you need and allow other elements to sit in the flow with me*. Your a tag has no text in it. **So it does not need to take up any space, so it doesn't.**

`inline-block` means *take up whatever space I'm configured to take up (defined in the CSS) and also allow elements to flow next to me*. So this applies the width and height, where as inline doesn't

The other option is `block`, this means *take up an entire row and don't let anything flow next to me*

Comment: Thanks Liam that worked, Can you please explain me about inline-block thing.

Comment: @frederim This seems to cover it pretty succinctly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/542251

Comment: Arg, sorry, I've just relaised what you mean't in the previous question, added some detail. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

A simple `display:block` or `display:inline-block` is the answer

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/sDQGr/)

```
#pageHeader h1 a {
    width:130px;
    height:70px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-130-70-8.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accessible way is

```
<h1><a href=...><img src=... alt=... border=0></a></h1>
```

Comment: Where do I put heading1 text in this one?

Comment: Into the `alt` attribute. If you mean that the link should contain a logo *and* a heading text (and not logo *as* a heading), then you would use `<h1><a href=...><img src=... alt="" border=0>heading</a></h1>`.

Answer (score -1):

for a javascript fix, could always add `onclick="location.href='yourblog';"` to your h1 tag