# button width for dynamic button text

Tags: html, css

I want something like this

**button1 button2**

but the problem is I can't set fixed width for the text within the button because it could be dynamic. And inline-block doesn't wor in my case?

http://jsfiddle.net/sV8LH/

```
<p><span class="btn">Reveal Identity</span><span class="btn">View similar candidates</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float them left, which will set auto width.

```
<p>
<span class="btn">Reveal Identity</span>
<span class="btn">View similar candidates</span>
<br clear="all" />
</p>

.btn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sV8LH/2/

Comment: float and the width will be auto? this is my first time knowing this!

Comment: As long as you don't declare it specifically (look at the fiddle.. I removed `width: 100%`

Comment: You can leave the `float` completely off, when using `inline-block` http://jsfiddle.net/sV8LH/4/

Comment: what is the differences btw float left and inline-block? they seem doing the same thing in my case

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block) is a good answer describing inline-block property. Inline means it is displayed in line with the document flow (like `<span>`). Block means it takes up full width and a line break following (like `<p>`). When you float an element, it is outside of the document flow and the rest of the content flows around it. Inline-block does not; document continues to flow as normal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

`display: inline;` rather then

```
display: inline-block;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sV8LH/6/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

`float:left` and `display:inline`

This will align the span elements next to one another by pulling them to one side(`float:left`)

**Just a Heads up:** add a `margin:value in px` to create buttons with inter-elemental space for better styling.