# Is \r needed for new line in php?

Tags: php, html

`echo("<li>Hello</li>\n");` seems to work fine for putting a new line in the HTML.

Is `\r` also required?  For instance, `echo("<li>Hello</li>\r\n");`

Thanks

Comment: It is for some systems particularly windows

Comment: @JohnConde Does anyone have a resource that explains exactly when `\r` is used? I haven't found the need to use it in a Windows environment however I know I've seen it before.

Comment: @JohnConde.  Ah, I see.  I must be using one of the browsers that work without it.

Comment: All browsers will translate the `\n` as a newline regardless of system if you see the source code, because it was rendered by the web server. You would only need the `\r\n` if you were writing that on a windows system and not using a web server to view the page.

Comment: When it comes to writing content to files on Windows, that's where it makes a more prominent difference. I quote from an entry on the [`PHP website`](http://www.php.net/fwrite) *"If you are writing data to a txt file on a windows system and need a line break. use \r\n"*

Comment: If you just want your HTML to show up as new lines in the source (*or to look "pretty" as you stated in another comment*) without having everything all clumped in single lines of code (*which I see all too often*) concatenate the last lines of code with `. "\n"` I.e.: `echo("<li>Hello</li>" . "\n");` and `echo "<table>" . "\n";` etc. that way you'll get nicely formatted and aligned HTML. I see these mistakes (*day in and day out*) having some (*next to*) unreadable code when it comes to debugging HTML. Using `<br>` will print `<br>` in the source, while `\n` won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your HTML to show up as new lines in the source (*or to look "pretty" as you stated in [`a comment you made`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566760/is-r-needed-for-new-line-in-php#comment34349121_22566816)*) without having everything all clumped in single lines of code, concatenate the last lines of code using `. "\n"`

I.e.: `echo("<li>Hello</li>" . "\n");` and `echo "<table>" . "\n";` etc. that way you'll get nicely formatted and aligned HTML.

Using `<br>` will print `<br>` in the HTML source, while using `\n` will not.

***For example:***

Using:

```
echo("<li>Hello</li>" . "\n");
echo("<li>Hello again</li>" . "\n");
echo("<li>Hello to you too</li>" . "\n");
```

The HTML source will be:

```
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Hello again</li>
<li>Hello to you too</li>
```

As opposed to using `<br>`

```
echo("<li>Hello</li>" . "<br>");
echo("<li>Hello again</li>" . "<br>");
echo("<li>Hello to you too</li>" . "<br>");
```

The HTML source will be:

```
<li>Hello</li><br><li>Hello again</li><br><li>Hello to you too</li><br>
```

This makes it harder to go through HTML source in order to troubleshoot/debug etc.

*That is only three lines of code; imagine having dozens or hundreds of lines?*

---

**Footnotes:**

Using `\r` is perfectly fine for echoing and will not affect your code if added or omitted; however you're just using more characters than is required when wanting to get clean well-formatted and aligned HTML source.

Just `\n` will suffice; for **echo'ed** output.

Comments have already been given under your original question in regards to using `\r` for the purpose and relation to files under Windows and older versions of MAC, therefore I won't repeat myself.

Comment: So, it sounds like the answer is "No, assuming you just want pretty HTML, then you do not need the `\r`, and should just use `\n`.

Comment: Exactly. As the others and myself have already stated, the `\r` is for Windows and older version of Mac. @user1032531 I always use `\n` at the end of my echo'ed codes and it's easier to follow in HTML source.

Comment: If you feel that any of the people (*including myself*) who have given you an answer and you consider being solved, then please mark one of them as accepted in order to close the question, if it did. Otherwise, your question will remain open and in the unanswered category. SO asks to close questions when answers have indeed properly answered an OP's question and/or solved it. @user1032531 Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The newline in this case is not because of the `\n`, but because of the `<li>`. HTML transforms Whitespace into a single space, unless you use something like `<pre>`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is never required. In fact the newline isn't required in HTML either.

Comment: I know it isn't "required".  Just want my HTML to look pretty.

Comment: Unless you specifically want to view your HTML source in Notepad the return isn't needed. Even in Windows and Mac HTML source viewers all recognize a newline properly.

Comment: It is required if you want to make a proper newline in command line scripts that run on windows and in windows txt files.

Comment: @EJTH We are talking about HTML not command line output here. Also, aside from Notepad, every text editor I've ever used in Windows understand either. The code to auto detect line endings is trivial so most developers will implement that.

Answer (score 0):

Not required. additionally, list items will always be on new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PHP_EOL` constant and PHP will use whatever is native on that platform.
See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Comment: But using PHP_EOL is pointless if your output is going to different OS's. e.g. a linux php server sending output to a Mac.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked on my FF browser.  My purpose is just pretty HTML, not including a `<br>`.  Is this a good use?

Comment: Yeah, `PHP_EOL` is not relevant when it comes to output.

Comment: This is not what you want. This is much more cumbersome to use and you are wanting something to display correct on the client machine (not your server).

Answer (score 0):

In HTML You have always to use

```
"<br />"

<?php echo "<div>HELLO</div><br />"; ?>
```

BUT, I had this problem to save a text on a file.

On windows just the **\n** to break line didn't work, when I opened the file in a text editor all the text was in the same row, so I had to use **\n\r**

Answer (score 0):

Well, the various operating systems use different newline characters, but in practice browsers understand most of the newline conventions, i.e. `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`.

> 3.7.1 Canonicalization and Text Defaults
>
> [...]
>
> When in canonical form, media subtypes of the "text" type use CRLF as
>   the text line break. *HTTP relaxes this requirement and allows the
>   transport of text media with plain CR or LF alone representing a line
>   break* when it is done consistently for an entire entity-body. **HTTP
>   applications MUST accept CRLF, bare CR, and bare LF as being
>   representative of a line break** in text media received via HTTP. [...]

Source: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt (emphasis by me). `LF` stands for "Line Feed" and is the `\n` character. `CR` stands for "Carriage Return" and is the `\r` character.

The problems with newline characters will only come up if you open the source code in some text editors. For instance, Linux newlines (`\n`) may cause the text to be displayed on one line in Notepad (which uses Windows' `\r\n` newline). This may not happen in newer version of Notepad, but it is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

To force a new line use this:

```
    echo("<li>Hello</li> <br />");
```

**NOTE:** A `<li>` element is by default a HTML block element, so a new line is generated automatically.

If you had a stylesheet with the following code

```
    li {
          display: inline;      /*changes block-Element into an inline-Element*/
       }
```

the `<br />` would be needed to force a new line.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block) if you want to know more about block and inline elements in HTML.

Comment: `<li>Hello</li> <br />` is invalid HTML. I think the OP meant new lines in the source code.

Comment: This isn't what the OP asked for but `<li>Hello</li> <br />` IS valid HTML.

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of valid. It displays exactly as intended on all modern browsers. I'd say that makes it valid but if we run it through a validator it would fail.