# why inline-block renderes slightly below complared block?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

On setting the inner div to inline-block, it renders slight below that of a block. Why is that ?

**http://jsfiddle.net/Sb9Wb/**

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
    <p> This is a inner div</p>
    <p>Height set to 100%</p>
    <p>Why it renderes slightly below when set to inline-block that of a block?</p>
</div>
```

Please try setting the inner div as block and see the difference!

And the same inline-block adds a scrollbar here **http://jsbin.com/kabom/1/edit**

Just because, a class below is added to a div!

```
.sapUiView {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a small image to show where that shift is?

Comment: The differences are here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sb9Wb/ Do you mean this???

Answer (score 1):

That space you are actually seeing is caused by the "p" margin that becomes visible when you add the inline-block property.

Try adding

```
 margin:0;
```

to the first child of p like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Sb9Wb/2/

Comment: "Becomes visible" may be better described as "not condensed as per normal rules" because the `inline-block` defines a new margin context.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! But can you check why it adds a scrollbar here http://jsbin.com/kabom/1/edit for the same reason !