# Problems with display inline

Tags: html, css, inline

I'm creating a website with drop down navigation, but in it my `div`s (the ones with display inline) aren't displaying inline. I don't believe that I am doing anything wrong, but the display inline is not working.

The gist of it is that this code:

```
<h1 id="name">LFX Music</h1>
<div class="click-nav" style="display: inline;">
<ul class="no-js">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicker">Profile</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Privacy</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sign out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="click-nav1" style="display: inline;">
<ul class="no-js1">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicker1">Profile</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Privacy</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sign out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="scripts/js/navigation.js"></script>
```

Doesn't dislpay the two `div`s side by side

Here is the jsfiddle with all of the code:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leoalfredmusic/bC5Gr/)

Also, is there a better way I can process the menu with jQuery?

Thanks, for your help!

Comment: and when you use: `div { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:inline` use `float:left` or  `display: inline-block`

```
div {
    float:left;
}
```

or

```
div {
      display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want to know the difference between `display:inline` and `display:inline-block` take a look at *[**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)* .

As for `float:left` it's pretty much self explanatory but ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568272/how-css-float-works-why-height-of-the-container-element-doesnt-increase-if-it)*** can help.