# Why margin:0 auto can't center image in div levelly?

Tags: html, css

The image element can be centered levelly with `margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9OIT14w.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

In the situation, `margin:0 auto; ==  margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;`.
So it is equal to write `margin:0px 50px 0px 50px;` as `margin:0 auto;`.
Why it can't be centered with `margin:0 auto;`?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9OIT14w.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: It works in the previous case because you have a fixed margin, and you can apply a fixed margin to inline elements. In the second example, you need to add `display: block` - that's needed to center an element with `margin: auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You miss `display:block`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.img1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="img1" src="http://i.imgur.com/9OIT14w.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better / more efficient ways of doing this. but...

This is what I use for centering images inside a `div` both vertically and horizontally while **maintaining** the div's fixed **dimensions**. The images are never **cropped** / **stretched**.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.my-image-parent {
  margin:1em auto;
  width: 350px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px; /* should match your div height */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  background: #131418;
}


/*fluff */
.bg1 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/799/799);}
.bg2 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/800/400);}
.bg3 {background: url(https://unsplash.it/400/800);}
/* end fluff */


.my-image {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h4>Works for square, landsacape and portrait images.</h4>

<div class="my-image-parent">
  <div class="my-image bg1"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="my-image-parent">
  <div class="my-image bg2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="my-image-parent">
  <div class="my-image bg3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `img` tag is an `inline-block` element, `margin: 0 auto;` will not work. Its display property has to be set to `display: block;`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9OIT14w.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

You can also add `text-align: center;` for the outer wrapper to center the image.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9OIT14w.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Edit:

Inline and inline-block elements do not have a width property, and so the "auto" cannot be calculated.

Reference : [Why centering with margin 0 auto works with display:block but does not work with display:inline-block ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442060/why-centering-with-margin-0-auto-works-with-displayblock-but-does-not-work-with)