# What is the need to make image display property as block inside div to center it?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and want to understand some basics. What is the need to set image display property as block to center it inside div ?

```
#logo {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
```

How does changing the display to block change the behaviour of img element inside div (how does it help center image)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442060/why-centering-with-margin-0-auto-works-with-displayblock-but-does-not-work-with/24442364#24442364

Answer (score 2):

`img` is an inline element so setting it `display: block` will completely change how it flows on the page

Comment: can you explain more how it changes the behaviour inside div on changing from inline to block

Comment: @madcolonel10  Block level elements do not sit inline but break past them. By default (without setting a width) they take up as much horizontal space as they can.So if they take a line you can get the center of it and place your image there