# CSS - Div Not Centering

Tags: css

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.holder{
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #424242;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.detailBox {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="holder">
    <div class="detailBox">
     <div class="content" id="row1">
      <div class="wordInputContainer">
       <div class="inputBox">
        
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="content" id="row2">
      <div class="wordOutputContainer">
       <div class="listBox">
        <!-- List Elements Go Here -->
        <!-- Words Output In Alphabetical Order [A - Z] -->
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="content" id="row3">
      <div class="wordStatisticContainer">
       <div class="wordCount"></div>
       <div class="commonLetter"></div>
       <div class="commonWord"></div>
       <div class="longestWord"></div>
       <div class="shortestWord"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

[image: img]

Even though I have `margin: 0 auto;` on the `.detailedBox` it still isn't centering. Is it because it doesn't have a fix width? It doesn't have a fixed width because I want the `.detailedBox` to be the width of all the `.content`'s combined, but also centered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [margin:auto; with inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076919/marginauto-with-inline-block) AND/OR [Why centering with margin 0 auto works with display:block but does not work with display:inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442060/why-centering-with-margin-0-auto-works-with-displayblock-but-does-not-work-with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.detailBox` is set to `inline-block`, it cannot be centered by using `margin:0 auto`. One way to understand this is that the "margin centering" technique relies on "filling up" available horizontal space. But there is no available space when using an inline element. (Reference: [margin:auto; with inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076919/marginauto-with-inline-block).)

Also note that:

> 10.3.9 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow
>   If 'width' is 'auto', the used value is the shrink-to-fit width as for floating elements.
>   A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a used value of '0'.
>   — [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)

One alternative is to let `.detailBox` default to `display:block` and set `text-align:center` to horizontally center it's child `.content` elements, which are `inline-block`.

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.holder {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0%;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #424242;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.detailBox {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="detailBox">
      <div class="content" id="row1">
        <div class="wordInputContainer">
          <div class="inputBox">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="row2">
        <div class="wordOutputContainer">
          <div class="listBox">
            <!-- List Elements Go Here -->
            <!-- Words Output In Alphabetical Order [A - Z] -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="row3">
        <div class="wordStatisticContainer">
          <div class="wordCount"></div>
          <div class="commonLetter"></div>
          <div class="commonWord"></div>
          <div class="longestWord"></div>
          <div class="shortestWord"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You mentioned that you want `.detailBox` to be the width of all the content combined. So, if for some reason you need `.detailBox` to remain `inline-block`, you could set `text-align:center` on *it's* parent, `.holder`. Like this:

```css
body {
  background: #212121;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.holder {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0%;
  text-align:center;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #424242;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.detailBox {
  height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="detailBox">
      <div class="content" id="row1">
        <div class="wordInputContainer">
          <div class="inputBox">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="row2">
        <div class="wordOutputContainer">
          <div class="listBox">
            <!-- List Elements Go Here -->
            <!-- Words Output In Alphabetical Order [A - Z] -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="row3">
        <div class="wordStatisticContainer">
          <div class="wordCount"></div>
          <div class="commonLetter"></div>
          <div class="commonWord"></div>
          <div class="longestWord"></div>
          <div class="shortestWord"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change `.detailBox` to have `display: flex` (instead of inline-block) and then do `justify-content: center` then it'll center that div horizontally.

Comment: I love your answer because its short and sweet, but since stack overflow is more about helping future users who may stumble upon this problem I have to choose a answer that is in more detail and explains whats going on in detail.