# Display Rules for Whitespace for Elements inside Inline Spans

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I am having a weird issue where I tend to think that a space should exist, but browsers clobber it.  At the very least, I cannot quite understand the underlying logic for the behavior of how spaces are handled in elements that live inside an `display: inline-block;`.  For example:

```
<p>
Space in an inline: This will have no<span style="display: inline-block;" class="bold"> space in it.</span>
</p>
<p>
<span style="display: inline-block;">Space btw inlines: This will have a</span> <span style="display: inline-block;" class="bold"><span> space in it.</span></span>
</p>
<p>
Space in the span: This will have a<span> space in it.</span>
</p>
```

Produces the HTML display:

> Space in an inline: This will have nospace in it.
>
> Space btw inlines: This will have a space in it.
>
> Space in the span: This will have a space in it.

Which is weird for a few reasons.  First, in the first case, the space between no and space still exists.  Copy and paste, and it will be in your text (see: http://jsfiddle.net/gdhgmj7g/2/).  However, it won't be shown in the web page.  Does anyone know the rules for how this is actually handled?  Is this a bug or somehow intended behavior?  Weirdest of all, the first case has a space in the span, you just can't see it unless you copy-paste the content.  The second has a space between the inline spans, which then allows things to display reasonably.  Likewise, in a normal paragraph (third case), things work as expected.  This behavior occurs consistently for IE, Firefox, and Chrome, so I would assume some logic is behind it.  But I have zero idea why it is.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block) might help.

Comment: I don't quite see the relevance to the particular weirdness that I am seeing?  Is there a reason why an inline block shouldn't be able to have a space inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element that is `display:inline-block` is a inline-level, block container.

Like all block containers, it's made up of a vertical stack of line boxes. In your first case of the inline-block span, the stack is just one line box high.

The [white-space](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/text.html#white-space-prop) rules apply to that line box. The rules state that:

> As each line is laid out,
>
> 1. If a space (U+0020) at the beginning of a line has 'white-space' set to
>      'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is removed.
> 2. All tabs (U+0009) are rendered as a horizontal shift that lines up the
>         start edge of the next glyph with the next tab stop. Tab stops
>         occur at points that are multiples of 8 times the width of a space
>         (U+0020) rendered in the block's font from the block's starting
>         content edge.
> 3. If a space (U+0020) at the end of a line has 'white-space' set to
>         'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is also removed.
> 4. If spaces (U+0020) or tabs (U+0009) at the end of a line have 
>         'white-space' set to 'pre-wrap', UAs may visually collapse them.

So from rule 1 the space at the start of the span is "removed". Note that this is a **layout** behaviour. The space is still in the content, so when you copy and paste it the space is included.

In your second case, the space is between inline-block elements. It is neither at the start, nor end of the line, so it is not removed by the white-space layout rules.

In your third case, span elements are, by default, not block containers. They don't create a stack of line boxes, so the space is not at the start or end of a line box, and so it is not removed by the white-space layout rules.

Comment: Great.  That cleared it up quite nicely.  I think my confusion was that it treats the contents of an inline-block as a "line" with respect to the rule: "If a space (U+0020) at the beginning of a line has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line', it is removed."  I don't typically think of an inline element as a "line" per se, but apparently HTML does, which does make sense when you consider it as a wrapping column like you noted.