# Can't remove 1 pixel bottom border from <span> inside <td>;

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table

I have a simple table, and it has a 1 pixel space underneath the `<td>` elements.

I've tried getting rid of `margins/padding/border-collapse/border-spacing`/etc.., and it's still there.

Here's a simple case:

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <tr style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
        <td style='background-color: red; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'><span style='background-color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
                The first span
            </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
        <td style='background-color: red; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
            <span style='background-color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
                The second span
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also available at: http://jsfiddle.net/ydk4zob9/

On Chrome 41.0.2272.89 (but not firefox) I see 1 pixel of the red background from the `td` showing underneath the `span`

[image: Table on chrome]

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to set `span` to `display:inline-block`

why?

because `span` is an inline element therefore takes a whitespace in your HTML into account.

here is a snippet:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  background-color: red;
  padding:0;
}
span {
  background-color: white;
 
}
.first span {
  display: inline  /*the default value*/
}
.second span {
  display: inline-block
}

.third span {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<h1>Inline</h1>
<table class="first">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>The first span</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>The second span</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<h1>Inline-block</h1>
<table class="second">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>The first span</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>The second span</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<h1>Block</h1>
<table class="third">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>The first span</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>The second span</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### EDIT:

After the comments, here is a must read about [INLINE ELEMENTS vs INLINE-BLOCK ELEMENTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/3448527)

Comment: That solves it, but the reason doesn't quite make sense.  If I remove all the whitespace inside the table tags I still see the problem.  Why do we need inline-block if there is no whitespace inside the table?

Comment: because `span`by default is an `inline` element therefore takes a whitespace in HTML into account. as I stated in my answer below "why?" and if this solves your issue make sure you accept the answer :)

Comment: Actually that doesn't solve the problem on Chrome on Ubuntu - it actually now has a red border all the way around the span.  Furthermore, as my comment explains, I took out all the whitespace, so there shouldn't be spacing due to that - furthermore that wouldn't explain the border on the bottom.

Comment: See my updated answer and take a look at the differences between `inline`, `inline-block` &`block` and you will notice that in `inline` you have that extra 1px below `span`

Comment: @DavidLjungMadison - The "red border" is eliminated with `td { padding: 0; }` which acts the same as the deprecated `cellpadding="0"` attribute on the table which was removed in dippas example.

Comment: @misterManSam you are so right, I'm going to update the `padding`, when I updated the inline CSS to vanilla CSS I missed that property.

Comment: @misterManSam updated. Thanks for the reminder on the `padding`. This is what happen when we try to clean the code :)

Comment: Okay - I see that inline-block works, but I still don't see the why.  I can remove all the whitespace from the table in between the <table><tr><td> tags, and still get the border, so it can't just be the whitespace in the HTML.

Comment: please read the explanation that I already gave to you. what causes the whitespace it is ONLY the `span` being by default `display:inline`

Comment: Looking at explanations online, the reason for the space with inline is because of spaces and returns between HTML elements, such as "</div>   <div>", but I have taken these out (such as "</div><div>") and still see the problem.  Just using display:inline shouldn't add whitespace around an object.

Comment: For example:  https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

use border bottom instead using background color red

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;'>
    <tr style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
        <td style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'><span style='background-color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;border-bottom:1px solid red'>
                The first span
            </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
        <td style='margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0;'>
            <span style='background-color: white; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border-bottom:1px solid red'>
                The second span
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you got the question backwards - the red border showing is undesirable.