# Change hyperlink style

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to change a word in a hyperlink text.

Let's say the hyperlink is "foofoofoo". How to change the middle foo to italics?

I've tried this:

```
<a href="#">
foo<div style="font-style: italic;">foo<div>foo
</a>
```

However, my IDE states underlines the div as error and the whole hyperlink style gets messed up. 
Am I doing it wrong?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: try using an inline element like `span`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the middle foo in the italic  tag instead of a division.

```
foo<i>foo</i>foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a block element for this. You really should use an inline element like `span`.

```
<a href="#">
foo<span style="font-style: italic;">foo</span>foo
</a>
```

Here is a great write-up on the differences: [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot! I still have a lot to learn about web development! Thank you very much Daniel!

Comment: Hey @Daniel, I'm unable to upvote due to my low rep here. I'm sorry!