# How do I make HTML Elements appear on one line?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to have the H3 and P tags on the same line in pairs. I do not want to use the tag `<table>`.

HTML:

```
<h2>SERVERS:</h2>
<!--I want each set of H3 and P to be on the same line-->
<h3>Server 1 Status:</h3><p id="running">Running</p>
<h3>Server 2 Status:</h3><p id="notRunning">Not Running</p>
<h3>Server 3 Status:</h3><p id="running">Running</p>
```

CSS:

```
#running {
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#notRunning {
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I have been searching all over the place and most of the posts are either with the `<table>` tag or very old and don't work.

Comment: You can't use an id more than once in a page.

Comment: Yes you can... @cezar

Comment: I mean the same id. You use `id="running"` twice, that is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: @JeddDryden You can but you really shouldn't, `id`s should be unique http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id. Using the same `id` can cause problems, in this case `class` would be more appropriate.

Comment: You can use a class in CSS with preceding dot: `.running { attribute: value; }`. In HTML you just declare it like this: `<p class="my-class">`. And also don't use snake case in CSS. CSS is not case-sensitive and capital letters in your ids and classes don't make a lot of sense. It is better to write `<p id="not-running">` and in CSS `#not-runing { }`.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment I made a faux pas. It meant camel case and not snake case. Using a camel case isn't a best practice in HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use display:inline

```
h3,p{
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline`:

```
h3, p {
    display: inline;
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/5011843 for a good comparison of `display` options.

Answer (score 1):

use css like this, [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/7878dpyk/)

```
h3,p {

display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0v6p2w57/)**

```
p,h3{
display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit:**  **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0v6p2w57/3/)**

In your code there is a typo in this class

```
#notRunning {        
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

For next line, you can use clear or `<br/>` according to your requirement

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add css:

```
h3,p{
  display:inline;
}
```

and for each line add a `<br />` tag to it

[Demo](http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/MwvzrN)

Answer (score 1):

Edited code:

```
<h2>SERVERS:</h2>
    <!--I want each set of H3 and P to be on the same line-->
    <h3>Server 1 Status:</h3><p class="running">Running</p>
    <h3>Server 2 Status:</h3><p class="notRunning">Not Running</p>
    <h3>Server 3 Status:</h3><p class="running">Running</p>
```

Change "id" into class so it could be more specific and it won't apply to all your webpage, just the running and notRunning. CSS:

```
h3,p.running,p.notRunning {
display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution which lines them pairwise:

```
#running {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#notRunning {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3, p {
    display: inline;
}

h3::after {
    content: " ";
}

p::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

The assumption is that I can't access the HTML and have to do everything in CSS. The line `display: inline` just puts all headings and paragraphs on one line. With the pseudoselector `::after` we achieve some space in each pair and between the pairs vertically, and the line `display: block` takes care for a newline after every paragraph, thus putting every pair on single line.

And here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ucLmhx7t/1/