# why do CSS designer use display:block?

Tags: html, css

I have following code to place an image as an anchor, this is the skeleton code:

```
<html>
    <div id="outer"> 
    <div id="facebookButton">
    <a href="url"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

in the CSS:

```
    #facebookButton a{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
/*place code to load image*/
    }
```

what is purpose of the `display` property setting to **block** here? what are the benefits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display` property controls how the element is displayed on the page. It has several values, but the most commonly used ones are:

- **inline** Displays an element as an inline (like `<span>`).
- **block** Displays an element as a block element (like `<div>`).
- **none** Hides the element.

In your case, `<a>` is an inline element, so it's displayed among the text surrounding it:

```html
<p>This is <a href="" style="border: 1px solid blue;">a link</a> within text.</p>
```

But by changing its `display` property to `block`, it will be displayed like a `div` (a block that is separated from the text surrounding it) and you can control its height and width:

```html
<p>This is <a href="" style="display: block; border: 1px solid blue; width: 100px; height: 50px;">a link</a> within text.</p>
```