# inline div over a span do not cover full text height

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<div style="border:1.00px solid #000000;display:inline;">
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text</span>
</div>
```

I want to apply a border to cover the text only. The border do not cover the full height of the span. What is the reason?

Edit:

```
<div>
<div style="border:1.00px solid #000000;display:inline-block;">
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text this is some text this is some this is some text</span>
</div>
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text</span>
</div>
```

I changed "inline" to "inline-block". In that case a line spanning more than one line and having border not really only covers the text. What I am trying is, if only some part of the whole text has border. The border cover's the whole line. Is this normal or I can something for this ?

[I was expecting this output when using inline-block.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNdMK.png)

Comment: if you haven't figured out, check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **div** display to inline-block

```
<div style="border:1.00px solid #000000;display:inline-block;">
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text</span>
</div>
```

Because Elements with display:inline-block elements are like display:inline elements, but they can have a width and height. So you can use an inline-block element as a block to give border.

See this [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Comment: I edited my question after adding "inline-block". Now I have a different problem that the border covers the whole line and not covers only the text part.

Comment: @nav then check out my answer

Comment: Thanks DoughnutZombie. This is not what I am trying to accomplish. Let me edit my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use "display: inline-block;" instead of 'display:inline'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding`

```
<div style="border:2.00px solid #000000;display:inline-block; padding:4px ">
    <span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text</span>
    </div>
```

Jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/o9e2nktx/

**Edit:**

The problem that you are currently having is you haven't added the second span tag inside to the current `<div>`, so you should have to add that too, to cover the whole text.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q4gy5zun/1/

Else if you want it like your previous example, because your   `<div style="border:1.00px solid #000000;display:inline-block;padding:4px">` code is valid only for that particular `<div>` only, which means that you cannot cover the 5th "this is some text" part,which is out of that `<div>`.So you have to use `<br>`as follows.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q4gy5zun/2/

Answer (score 0):

Change the `display:inline;` to `display:inline-block;`
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lygg8L99/)

Answer (score 0):

Try display:inline-block instead of inline.. **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pg7b9o8L/1/)**

```
<div style="border:1.00px solid #000000;display:inline-block;">
<span style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `display:inline`,from the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add padding to the span, which can be different on different sides, try this and delete whichever border doesn't suit your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <div style="border:1.00px solid #000000;display:inline;">
      <span style="border: 2px solid red;padding: 10px;
         font-family:Arial;font-size:20pt;">this is some text</span>
  </div> 

</body>
```