# How do I vertically align elements within a li in that code?

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align the `a` links 1-4 under the class `dropdown-menu.`

In this example I'm trying to do this by displaying the `div` as a `table-row` but nothing worked.

**CODE**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1ebb90;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropdown-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 18px 22px;
}
div {
  display: table-row;
}
div a {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">

    <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown</a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    </div>

  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do it, but one simple way is to use `display: block` on the links. 
([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ggamir/68yoqsks/))

[Here's a related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block) related to how inline vs block work.

Answer (score 1):

[1] Get rid of `overflow: hidden` on the `ul`

[2] Make the dropdown absolutely positioned:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

[3] Establish the `li` as the parent.

```
li {
  ...
  position: relative;
}
```

[4] Set up a hovering rule over the anchor next to the hidden dropdown menu.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/b3gbowrn/

```css
body {
font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
max-width: 960px;                       
margin: 0 auto;                         
padding: 20px;                    
}

ul {
list-style-type: none;             
margin:0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #1ebb90; 
}

li {
float: left;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
border-right: none;
}

li:last-child {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);   
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

li a, .dropdown-btn {                  
display: inline-block;
padding: 18px 22px;

}

div {
display: table-row;
}

div a {
display: inline;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">

            <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown</a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu">                      
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks for this andy. can you tell me why you dont like the overflow?

Comment: With the overflow set to hidden, the dropdown menu won't be visible on hover. You could always use `overflow-x: hidden`, which still allows for vertical overflow.

Answer (score 1):

- use `inline-block` in `li`
- change your HTML to be semantically correct to a menu, by using `ul li` in dropdown
- apply to your dropdown  `position:absolute` and `top:100%` with `relative` to `li`
- if you want to make it show/hide, you can use `:hover` in `li`

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #1ebb90;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative
}
li a,
.dropdown-btn {
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 22px;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li> <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you are welcome @Richi888 `:)`, just remember the semantics ;)