# Can't scroll to the bottom of an absolute element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I can't scroll to the bottom of an absolutely positioned element inside an inline element in Chrome as soon as I add some div over it. It works fine in Firefox...

Here a minimalist code reproducing the problem:

```
<div>When you</div>
<div>remove</div>
<div>these divs</div>
<div>it works</div>
<div>fine in Chrome</div>
<div style="display:inline;position:relative;background:green;">
    <div style="position:absolute;background:red;">111
      <br>222
      <br>333
      <br>444
      <br>555
      <br>666
      <br>777
      <br>888
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p973qaty/9/

Comment: You can just add a height to the `div` see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p973qaty/10/

Comment: Or change to `inline-block` https://jsfiddle.net/p973qaty/11/

Comment: And this answer helps explain your isse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Comment: I can't make it inline-block and I can't set the height because the content of the box dynamic.

Comment: I very well understand the difference between inline and inline-block but the fact is that Chrome and Firefox behave differently...

Comment: I am surprised Firefox lets you, seems more of a Firefox bug and not an issue with Chrome.

Comment: Can you use javascript to set the height?

Answer (score 1):

It is very interesting... I found in `w3.org` specification that `overflow` applies to `block containers,  flex containers and grid containers`,  but in `developer.mozilla.org` is written that it applies to `block-level elements and inline-block elements`. And in the example that we have in Firefox it applies in `inline elements` also and in tests we can see that in Chrome it applies in `inline-block elements`.
Links to specs [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow-clipping) and [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)