# Placing links on one line in html

Tags: css, html

I have the following code the links appear on separate lines. How do I place them on a single line on the web page-

```
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
<p><a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a></p>
```

Comment: Don't use `<p></p>` tag here, just `<a href="new.php">Add a new record</a> <a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a> <a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a>`

Comment: Why do you use `<p>`? Is it a requirement? If you need to keep them, set their `display` to `inline`. If you don't need to keep them, then remove them and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can't change your html, one way is to add `display: inline` to your `<p>` tags.

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
<p><a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a></p>
```

Or if you will need to do things like specify height or width, `display: inline-block` would be the answer.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>
<p><a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a></p>
<p><a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a></p>
```

However, if you want them inline I wouldn't put each link in it's own paragraph, as this is not good practice. Remove the `<p>` tags, as below:

```html
<a href="new.php">Add a new record</a>
<a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a>
<a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a>
```

Comment: @C0dekid I'm not sure if it would make a difference in this case, but I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @C0dekid What `inline-block` has over `inline` is that you can add height and width - thats the only difference - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Comment: @C0dekid You do realize the OP said *How do I place them on a single line on the web page* right?

Comment: Oh.. i'm sleeping I think, I'm sorry! Haha, have my upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although it is possible to do it the way you did it with `p` tag I would recommend doing it with `ul` and then `li` tags.

```css
li
{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></li>
  <li><a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="new.php">Add a new record</a>
<a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a>
<a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a>
```

The `<p>` tag creates a new paragraph so if you want the links to appear in a single line, you just need to get rid of them

Answer (score 0):

Delete the p

```
<a href="new.php">Add a new record</a>
<a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a>
<a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="new.php">Add a new record</a>
<a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a>
<a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `display:inline-block`. Because `inline` elements can not have a width and height set, but `inline-block` elements respects height and width, respects top and bottom margins and paddings.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="new.php">Add a new record</a>
<a href="view.php">View, Edit or Delete Existing Records</a>
<a href="index.html">Go to Home Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`P` tag is block level element so it will take full width so if you need this in one line then you can add css `display:inline-block` for `p` tag.

Best way of navigation in one line:

You can use `ul` instead on `p` tag:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href"#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href"#">test</a></li>
    <li><a href"#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Css for above `HTML`:

```
li{display:inline-block}
```