# How can I center menu button for slicknav?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, slicknav

I want to center the menu menu button in [slicknav](http://slicknav.com/). I tried but nothing works . I can align it to the left but not in center.

sample mark up is here

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

and js

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu').slicknav();
});
```

here is codepen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLWpao

Comment: you want full menu in center??

Comment: yes , at last i soled it , http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXmQLG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to my question.

just added some css

```
.slicknav_menu {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.slicknav_btn {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This solved my problem.

here is codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXmQLG

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser inspect. All the elements are given a display: block, which gives it a full width. If you set the '.slicknav_nav a' on display: inline-block and the li parent a text-center, everything should be what you want.

```
.slicknav_nav a {
  display: inline-block; // instead of block;
}

.slicknav_nav li {
  text-align: center;
}
```

This might be some useful info: [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

```
.slicknav_menu {
    text-align: center;
}

.slicknav_btn { 
    display: inline-block; 
    float: none;
}
```