# Positioning divs inside a container

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a general, possibly beginner question about HTML.

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#item1 {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#item2 {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

My question is, why do `#item1` and `#item2` divs go underneath each other as opposed to next to each other? Isn't it true that they are no longer block-level elements because I have specified a set width for them? Why are they not lined up next to each other inside of `#container`? The `#container` has more than enough width to accommodate both items.

Note: This is strictly for learning/curiosity. I know that I can use margins and positioning to place them where I want to. However, I'm just curious as to why it behaves this way.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if you have set their widths, their property remains same as block. What you have to do is make them display:inline-block, then they will stand next to each other as you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div elements are block elements, unless you specify the display property to inline or inline-block it wont align to to the right like other inline elements do.

adding display : inline-block to the css of div's will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` tag always start with new line if you are not using frameworks like bootstrap or other. If you want to see multiple items in single line then add css like `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your class like below.

```
#item1{
    height:100px;
    max-width:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
}
#item2{
    height:100px;
    max-width:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I understand. When I do this though, I get a bit of space in between each div (#item1, #item2) why is this?

Comment: It is solved, it was because of the gap in the HTML code in between the divs. I had no idea that would actually affect the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The #container ie you div has a display property of block. This is a default property if you don't set it to anything else. In your case the div takes this default display property.

To view #item1 and #item2 side by side just use display: inline-block in your #container.

Answer (score 0):

`just add float:left; property in child divs or display:inline-block;`    https://jsfiddle.net/8tvn0kw6/5/

Answer (score 0):

`div` is the standard block-level element. A block-level element starts on a new line and stretches out to the left and right as far as it can. Other common block-level elements are p and form, and new in HTML5 are header, footer, section, and more.

Even if you specify width it wont allow other elements right next to it. This the property of block level element.

Use the css `inline-block` it will occupy the specified width or content width.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

The `height` of the container should be the **sum of heights of the child divs and the heights of the borders of the children**

ie., `height of parent container = 100+ 100+ 1+ 1+ 1+ 1 = 204px`

```
#container {
 height: 204px;
}
```

Comment: even when using box-sizing: border-box ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to place you blocks horizontally: **display** property or **float** property.

It doesn't matter that you have set width to your elements. They are still block and displayed vertically.
To change this behaviour, use stylesheet (note that in both cases **width**, not **max-width** should be set):

```
#container {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#item1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
#item2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

or this:

```
#container {
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#item1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}
#item2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: When using float it works perfectly. I'm just curious as to why there is a small gap between each div when using inline-block?

Comment: It is because of line-break in html code between divs. Remove line-break and you will see no gap.
Also u can use negative **margin-left**.
Also you can find a couple of methods to escape this gap in google. I don't remember them all :-)

Comment: Right, yea i was just curious about the cause of it because I had set no margins. Thank you.