# Background image won't show when in an #id selector but shows in body

Tags: html, css

I'm currently recreating the Google homepage for Odin and trying to set the logo as a background image. Whenever I put the background image and URL in the body for CSS - the logo will show. But when I then copy and paste the exact lines into logo, the image doesn't show up at all!

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#logo {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png");
  background-size: 272px 92px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <a href="www.google.co.uk" id="logo"></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: `<a id="logo">` is empty so it has zero width and zero height.

Comment: i tried previously to add a height and width to the id but it makes no difference?

Comment: That's because `<a>` tags are inline elements. You can't set a height or width. They get their dimensions from their content. Add `#logo { display: block; }` and you will be able to set the height and width.

Comment: you're amazing! it just popped up! thank you so very much for helping me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no content in the anchor tag.

If you do not want to give any content inside anchor tag you should make **display block** and provide and height Or you can also use **inline-block** providing width and height

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="main">
          <a href="www.google.co.uk" id="logo"></a>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>



* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo {
  background: url("imgs/google-logo.png");
  background-size: 272px 92px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: here we can set `height` as same as `background-size: ` `height` like setting `height:92px;` we won't get confused with next `elements` alignments(position).

Answer (score 0):

Anchors (`a` tag) are `inline` elements by default, i.e. the size is auto generated based on its contents. Since your tag is empty there's no size and nothing renders.

You can change the `display` to `block` or `inline-block` (read more about the both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)) and provide `width` and `height`.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#logo {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/2000px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png");
  background-size: 272px 92px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  width: 272px;
  height: 92px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Google</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" id="logo"></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```