# Aligning tweets in HTML

Tags: html, twitter

I already added tweets into my HTML page, but i'd like to have both of the tweets side by side.

Style code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif}
        h1 {letter-spacing: 6px}
        .w3-row-padding img {margin-bottom: 12px}
    </style>
</head>
```

My code is:

```
    <p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">In this area you can easily see tweets about movies!</p>
    <p style="text-align: center;">Have fun!</p>



        <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Sunsets don&#39;t get much better than this one over <a href="https://twitter.com/GrandTetonNPS">@GrandTetonNPS</a>. <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/nature?src=hash">#nature</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/sunset?src=hash">#sunset</a> <a href="EXAMPLE">pic.twitter.com/YuKy2rcjyU</a></p>&mdash; US Dept of Interior (@Interior) <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456">May 5, 2014</a></blockquote> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


        <blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">10 years before Kirk, Spock and the Enterprise, there was <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/Discovery?src=hash">#Discovery</a>.  <a href="EXAMPLE2">pic.twitter.com/wrKF3KXeOT</a></p>&mdash; IMDb (@IMDb) <a href="https://twitter.com/IMDb/status/864981989358657536">May 17, 2017</a></blockquote> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In the example below, i'd like to have both of those tweets side by side.

[image: Example of the website]

Comment: and where is your css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
.twitter-tweet {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```css
body,
h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif
}

h1 {
  letter-spacing: 6px
}

.w3-row-padding img {
  margin-bottom: 12px
}

.twitter-tweet {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">In this area you can easily see tweets about movies!</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Have fun!</p>



<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Sunsets don&#39;t get much better than this one over <a href="https://twitter.com/GrandTetonNPS">@GrandTetonNPS</a>. <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/nature?src=hash">#nature</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/sunset?src=hash">#sunset</a>    <a href="EXAMPLE">pic.twitter.com/YuKy2rcjyU</a></p>&mdash; US Dept of Interior (@Interior) <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456">May 5, 2014</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">10 years before Kirk, Spock and the Enterprise, there was <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/Discovery?src=hash">#Discovery</a>.  <a href="EXAMPLE2">pic.twitter.com/wrKF3KXeOT</a></p>&mdash; IMDb (@IMDb) <a href="https://twitter.com/IMDb/status/864981989358657536">May 17, 2017</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Option 2:

```
twitterwidget {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```css
body,
h1 {
  font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif
}

h1 {
  letter-spacing: 6px
}

.w3-row-padding img {
  margin-bottom: 12px
}

twitterwidget {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<p style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">In this area you can easily see tweets about movies!</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Have fun!</p>



<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Sunsets don&#39;t get much better than this one over <a href="https://twitter.com/GrandTetonNPS">@GrandTetonNPS</a>. <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/nature?src=hash">#nature</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/sunset?src=hash">#sunset</a>    <a href="EXAMPLE">pic.twitter.com/YuKy2rcjyU</a></p>&mdash; US Dept of Interior (@Interior) <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456">May 5, 2014</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


<blockquote class="twitter-tweet">
  <p lang="en" dir="ltr">10 years before Kirk, Spock and the Enterprise, there was <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/Discovery?src=hash">#Discovery</a>.  <a href="EXAMPLE2">pic.twitter.com/wrKF3KXeOT</a></p>&mdash; IMDb (@IMDb) <a href="https://twitter.com/IMDb/status/864981989358657536">May 17, 2017</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: @Luís for more about `block` and `inline-block` read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Answer (score 0):

in `<style>` add for class twitter-tweet

```
.twitter-tweet{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

blockquote is a block element and you want them inline

Answer (score 0):

If you use a framework like Bootstrap you can wrap the elemens in a `<div class="row">` and then add `class="col-sm-6"` into the tag for each one. This will group the elements into a row and for them predetermined width.