# The height of the body in the iframe is the same as the iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a question about the height of the body in the iframe .

`body` is a block-level element，so if I don't set the height and nothing in body,the height of body is 0;

[image]

Now, I find that, when body in iframe, it's height is always the same as iframe.(if iframe has it's own height)

for example: 
a html file , iframe is empty, it's height is `500px`.

body in the iframe is empty too, it's height is `500px` too.

**why body is empty but it's height is the same as iframe?**

I see `Quirks Mode` in some blogs，but It will appear in `html5` with `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        iframe{
            width:500px;
            height:500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Seems this css property is your main BODY. its not showing your iframe's height.
Can you provide jsfiddle demo so I can identify issue :)

Comment: Yes, your iframed document will be in quirks mode since it doesn't have a doctype, even if the container document is in standards mode.

Comment: @SanjayKanani https://jsfiddle.net/zh4fops8/, I know body will inheriting the iframe's height. but I do not know why. Is it related to the html document type or to the W3C standard or is it related to the implementation of the browser?  The code in my question is all. Nothing in body,even nothing in iframe. I just change the iframe's height by css. why body will inheriting ? body is a block-level element, if nothing in body , should it's height be 0?

Comment: @Alohciand I  have just tried it. If the ifame does not have `src`,so it does not have `doctype`,so it will  be in quirks mode.? If I set the attribute  `src='./2.html'` ,and `2.html` has `doctype`.body's height will be true,not 100%, thanks.

Comment: That is because Body deafult display css is block which is taking with and height of parent. Change display : inline ,and inline-block .
for more info look out this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Comment: I met another wired situation: two iframes with `src="about:blank"` and `srcdoc=""`, their content body has two different height calculated in the dev tools. And I tested another iframe with an empty page `src="empty.html"`, the height of its content body is also 0 like the empty `srcdoc` situation

Answer (score -1):

I has the same problem before, but I can answer to your question. The body inside the Iframe took the same height because it inheriting the parent height that means iframe height whatever we defined. For example,

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300px"></iframe>
```

So the height of the body inside of iframe would be "300px".

Comment: I know body will inheriting the iframe's height. but I do not know why. Is it related to the html document type or to the W3C standard or is it related to the implementation of the browser?  The code in my question is all. Nothing in body,even nothing in iframe. I just change the iframe's height by css. why body will inheriting ? body is a block-level element, if nothing in body , should it's height be 0?

Comment: The purpose of using iframe to load contents from another source, in your code tehre is no source for the iframe. 
iframe itself have a structure that html page has. Thats the reason the body has the same height what iframe has in your code.