# Problems with horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems in trying to distinguish the difference between `display: block` and `display: inline-block` in the example of horizontal menu.

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dg0ukk6/

The following lines of code is extracted from the fiddle link mentioned above

```
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Should I use `display: block` or `display: inline-block`? As I see the result is almost the same. What is exactly the difference between them in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Comment: remove the `float: left` and try switching them, and you can see the difference... well, here both produce the same result, and I guess it doesn't matter :)

Comment: @Maharkus This question is not really a duplicate of the link you posted. The OP seems familiar with the difference between the two, but is not understanding why he cannot see the difference in the code. See my answer below which addresses this.

Answer (score 2):

You notice no differences because you're applying that style to a single child inside a parent.

Check here, I've put two links inside the same `li`, notice the difference between

```
li a {
  display: block;
```

and

```
li a {
  display: inline-block;
```

[Display: Block](https://jsfiddle.net/wej0yf3m/)

[Display: Inline-block](https://jsfiddle.net/h7L3x01n/)

Comment: I've got it! :D Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not so much with your `a` element as it is with your `li` element. This is because the `a` elements are nested inside of your `li` elements.

Your `li` elements are currently being floated to the left so will line up next to each other. Any changes you make to the `a` elements only effect how they display inside of the `li` element. In your case it does not really make much of a difference unless you have more than one `a` element inside each `li`.

If you really want to see how things change you will want to change the display of the parent `li` elements. So instead of the following code:

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```

try one of these two options to see the difference:

```
li {
  display: block;
}
```

or

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements with display:inline-block are like display:inline elements, but they can have a width and a height. That means that you can use an inline-block element as a block while flowing it within text or other elements.

Difference of supported styles as summary:

```
inline: only margin-left, margin-right, padding-left, padding-right
inline-block: margin, padding, height, width
```

Answer (score 0):

**display: block**

When You use display:block to **li a** you can have one  in one li in one row

in other hand

**display: inline-block** 
When You use display:inline-block to **li a** you can have multiple  in one li in one row