# Unable to set width of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set the width of the div with a class **colors** either in percentage or in pixels but I am failing to do it.

```js
var colors = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PURPLE"];
for (var h = 0; h <= 4; h++) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= colors.length - 1; i++) {
    var element = "<div class='colors' id='color" + i + "'>" + colors[i] + "</div>";
    var sample = "sahdkj";
    $('#gameContainer').append(element);
  };
  $('#gameContainer').append("<br/><br/>");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 407px;
}

.colors {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="gameContainer">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You have 3 good answers... Please select one and close that easy question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 4):

Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;`

```js
var colors = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PURPLE"];
for (var h = 0; h <= 4; h++) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= colors.length - 1; i++) {
    var element = "<div class='colors' id='color" + i + "'>" + colors[i] + "</div>";
    var sample = "sahdkj";
    $('#gameContainer').append(element);
  };
  $('#gameContainer').append("<br/><br/>");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 500px;
}

.colors {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="gameContainer">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is `display: inline;`, you can not set `width` or `height`
>   to inline element e.g `<span>`, use `display: inline-block;` instead.

this is your updated code.

```js
var colors = ["RED", "GREEN", "BLUE", "YELLOW", "PURPLE"];
for (var h = 0; h <= 4; h++) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= colors.length - 1; i++) {
    var element = "<div class='colors' id='color" + i + "'>" + colors[i] + "</div>";
    var sample = "sahdkj";
    $('#gameContainer').append(element);
  };
  $('#gameContainer').append("<br/><br/>");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #e7e7e7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 407px;
}

.colors {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="gameContainer">

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code `width`, `height`, `padding`, `margin` dose not work properly on inline element what is you set by CSS `display: inline;`

```
.colors {
        display: inline-block; /*Modified line*/
        border: 1px solid black;
        vertical-align:top; /* added line, best practice when you apply "display: inline-block;" */
        width: 20%;
        position: relative;
        top:10px;
        bottom: 10px;
        margin:10px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change display property of **.colors** class **inline** to **inline-block**

**inline-block** elements are like **inline** elements but they can have a width and a height.

Answer (score 0):

Change display: inline;   -> display: inline-block;