# How to control the clickable area of an image? CSS

Tags: html, css

Even though the image is in the center of the page somehow I can click on the entire width of the image, which interferes with the hamburger feature of the page. Where did I go wrong?

The CSS:

```
.logo img{
  margin-left: 7.8%;
  float:left;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 769px) {
 .logo img{
  float:none;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a fiddle, snippet or the complete code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What part is the image?

Comment: The red square in the middle of the image.

Answer (score 3):

You have the `.logo img` as `display:block`, which will take up the entire width of it's parent container. I would change that to `display:inline-block`

See here: ([What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block))

Comment: Yes but if I do that the image is not centered anymore.

Comment: if you'd like to leave it block, that's fine; then you'll need to adjust your hamburger menu (which should be absolutely positioned atop (fixed or otherwise) anyway, just ensure the z-index is higher than your image.

It really depends on your design/html markup; but the general issue here is block-leveling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display-flex` to align items easily. `z-index: -1` will allow hamburger to capture the event and not the image.Try to click on the hamburger placeholder div and image and see the respective click working

```css
/* Styles go here */
header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

div.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hamburger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}

img {
  line-height: 80;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class='hamburger' onClick='alert("hamburger")'></div>
  <div class="img-container"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50" onClick='alert("image")'></div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like @Napoli sayed, and because I can't see your html code... you should use `display:inline-block` and then give a margin to center it like `margin: 0 auto;`