# Why does the text in the header doesn't fill it's box?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to coding and I am struggling to make the text fill the box. When I increase font size- the font gets bigger and so does the purple box so the text always ends up looking too small.

```
   #header {

background: #9800A3;
border-radius:10px;
border: 1px solid #84008f;
margin: 5px;
font-family: "Georgia";
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:3em;
font-size-adjust: auto;}
```

Comment: Please add part of the code with which you're struggling.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using either the div or header tag in the html file, both of them are `block` elements.

You need to make it `inline-block` element so that it takes up width based on the content.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14033814/3769582) might help you in understanding display properties more.

```css
#header {
  background: #9800A3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #84008f;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: "Georgia";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-size-adjust: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">abcd</header>
```