# Why do not inline-block elements occupy full width even on width 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

```js
let lastSelectButton;

document.querySelectorAll('.primaryButton').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (lastSelectButton) document.querySelector(`#${lastSelectButton} + div`).classList.toggle('inlb');
    lastSelectButton = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
    document.querySelector(`#${lastSelectButton} + div`).classList.toggle('inlb');
  }, false);
});
```

```css
button {
  text-align: left;
}

.primaryButton {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.secondaryButton {
  background: #d4d4d4;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

.primaryButton:hover {
  background: #a1a1a1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.secondaryButton:hover {
  background: #bfbfbf;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.inlb {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="primaryButton" id="p1">A</button>
<div class="none">
  <button class="secondaryButton">1</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">2</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">3</button>
</div>
<button class="primaryButton" id="p2">B</button>
<div class="none">
  <button class="secondaryButton">1</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">2</button>
</div>
<button class="primaryButton" id="p3">C</button>
<div class="none">
  <button class="secondaryButton">1</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">2</button>
</div>
```

As seen, the secondary buttons do not occupy full width like the primary buttons. Why does this happen? How to correct it?

On the contrary, setting `inline-block`s to `block`s settles the matter:

```js
let lastSelectButton;

document.querySelectorAll('.primaryButton').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (lastSelectButton) document.querySelector(`#${lastSelectButton} + div`).classList.toggle('inlb');
    lastSelectButton = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id');
    document.querySelector(`#${lastSelectButton} + div`).classList.toggle('inlb');
  }, false);
});
```

```css
button {
  text-align: left;
}

.primaryButton {
  display: block;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.secondaryButton {
  background: #d4d4d4;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: 1em;
}

.primaryButton:hover {
  background: #a1a1a1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.secondaryButton:hover {
  background: #bfbfbf;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.inlb {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="primaryButton" id="p1">A</button>
<div class="none">
  <button class="secondaryButton">1</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">2</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">3</button>
</div>
<button class="primaryButton" id="p2">B</button>
<div class="none">
  <button class="secondaryButton">1</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">2</button>
</div>
<button class="primaryButton" id="p3">C</button>
<div class="none">
  <button class="secondaryButton">1</button>
  <button class="secondaryButton">2</button>
</div>
```

What happens when I do this that solves the problem?

Edit: This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block) question, the main issue of in my question is buttons taking full width, while the other question asks for a differences between `display: inline-block` and `display: block` .

Comment: add `width:100%;` to the `.inlb` class, and your inline block displays width 100% ... like you want

Comment: @Bravo I just realized, that the width problem is due to the `div`s with class `none`. They don't occupy full width. Do you have any idea why do they take the width they do instead of taking full width?

Comment: @StephanVierkant That question has the general explanation to what `inline-block` and `block` elements are, but in my question the problem is to have the buttons take the full width, whose root cause is a different issue.

Comment: in both case you button is taking full width of its container, now the issue is the container that only take full width of its own container when it's block not inline block (thus the difference between block and inline block

Comment: @TemaniAfif But why do the containers take the width they do in `inline-block` vs full width in `block`? Even that is inconsistent, like in secondary buttons of `A` and `B`

Comment: you simply need to understand the difference between block and inline-block (check the duplicates)