# How can I make my image be inlined with my section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my section & image be inlined with each other and I've tried setting `display: inline;` on the image but it doesn't work.

```css
body {
    font-family: Glory;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"Glory";
    src: url("../fonts/Glory.ttf") format("truetype");
}    

header {
    background-color: #5CDB95;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
    color: #EDF5E1;
    margin: 0% 1.5%;
}

header nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li {
    margin-right: 5vh;
    margin-left: 15vh;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: #05386B;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

/* Section */
section {
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #5CDB95;
    text-align: center;
}

section h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}

section p {
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #47c580; 
}

.selfie {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <h1>MIN WEBBSIDA</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Intressen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Framtiden</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2>Vem är benim</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea cupiditate eveniet libero numquam iste unde quisquam quam, tempore perferendis? Rerum assumenda delectus quisquam molestias. Cupiditate corporis non culpa illo repellat!</p>
    </section>

    <img class="selfie" width="30%" src="img/selfie.jpg">
```

I know it's a pretty rookie question but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` on the `<section>` and `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

Add another HTML element (I called it `container` but it can be any `div` with an assigned class) and put your `section` and `img` inside.

Then, style your container with

```css
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
```

```
And you will have them side by side. You can play around with [Flexbox][1] to have a wider range of possibilities once you set
```

display: flex to an element.

```css
body {
    font-family: Glory;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@font-face {
    font-family:"Glory";
    src: url("../fonts/Glory.ttf") format("truetype");
}    

header {
    background-color: #5CDB95;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
    color: #EDF5E1;
    margin: 0% 1.5%;
}

header nav ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

header nav ul li {
    margin-right: 5vh;
    margin-left: 15vh;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: #05386B;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
    color: grey;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

/* Section */
section {
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #5CDB95;
    text-align: center;
}

section h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
}

section p {
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #47c580; 
}

.selfie {
    float: right;
}

container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <h1>MIN WEBBSIDA</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Intressen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Framtiden</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <container>
    <section>
        <h2>Vem är benim</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea cupiditate eveniet libero numquam iste unde quisquam quam, tempore perferendis? Rerum assumenda delectus quisquam molestias. Cupiditate corporis non culpa illo repellat!</p>
    </section>

    <img class="selfie" width="30%" src="img/selfie.jpg">

</container>
```

Comment: Thank you! this works really well, however I'm having one last difficulty, my section, I want it to be less wide and also the height is way too extended. How could I fix this? This is what I mean by the height being too much https://prnt.sc/1s6urar

Comment: I see your `section` has `width: 30%;` so on a wider screen will take more space. You can set a number of px there to have the size the same everywhere.

Comment: What about the height that it adds? like below the paragraph

Comment: The element `p` has some margin given by the browser. You can add `margin-bottom: 0;` to `section p` and should make it

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `section` to `display: inline-block;` and the section and the image will be vertically aligned. I assume this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `section` is also a block element, so your image will always be on a new line.

Try setting `section` to `display: inline-block` (not `inline` because you also set `width` for it here), and then you can set your `img` to `inline` :

```
section {
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #5CDB95;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;

}
.selfie {
    display: inline;
}
```

See the differences between `inline` and `inline-block` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)