# Force Elements Onto New Line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to push a div with images underneath a couple of arrow icons, that do not take up a whole row, as seen below. However, the images underneath keep wrapping in between the arrows, which is not the desired result. I was wondering if someone can please advise how to fix this? The example I inserted only works in narrower viewports because I pulled it from my mobile site I am working on. I am confused why two separate divs are overlapping in this way. Thanks in advance.

```css
#photo-viewer-outer-wrap div {
  display: inline;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
  clear: both;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right img {
  max-width: 30%;
}

#left-arrow {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#right-arrow {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo-viewer-outer-wrap">
  <div id="photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left">
    <img src="https://www.russorizio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ef3-placeholder-image.jpg" />
    <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-arrow-right-icon-2817-thumb.png" id="right-arrow" title="Next image" alt="next image" />
    <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/365/868/small/Basic_Elements__28113_29.jpg" id="left-arrow" title="Previous image" alt="previous image" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right">
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the `display: inline` on your outer div it seems. See a simplified version without the outer div: https://jsfiddle.net/d9rueyov/39/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using display inline property in a div which force div to take as much as space it needs and allows another div to join it.  [check these for learning display properties](https://css-tricks.com/when-do-you-use-inline-block/) [link2](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp)

[check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

```css
#photo-viewer-outer-wrap div {
  display: block;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
  clear: both;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right img {
  max-width: 30%;
}

#left-arrow {
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#right-arrow {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo-viewer-outer-wrap">
  <div id="photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left">
    <img src="https://www.russorizio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ef3-placeholder-image.jpg" />
    <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-arrow-right-icon-2817-thumb.png" id="right-arrow" title="Next image" alt="next image" />
    <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/365/868/small/Basic_Elements__28113_29.jpg" id="left-arrow" title="Previous image" alt="previous image" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right">
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
    <img src="https://buildyourspechere.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/placeholder-image-person-jpg.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used `flex` for you. No need to `float` and `display: inline`:

```css
#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left img:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

#left-arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 10px;
}

#right-arrow {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px 10px 20px 0;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 300px;
}

#photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right img {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<div id="photo-viewer-outer-wrap">
  <div id="photo-viewer-inner-wrap-left">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/7560b48482bfae5c-02b97ffc647f-3822363654_tji3.jpg" />
    <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/000/365/868/small/Basic_Elements__28113_29.jpg" id="left-arrow" title="Previous image" alt="previous image" />
    <img src="https://www.iconpacks.net/icons/2/free-arrow-right-icon-2817-thumb.png" id="right-arrow" title="Next image" alt="next image" />
  </div>
  <div id="photo-viewer-inner-wrap-right">
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/5c29cf910a706_8m.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```