# What is the difference between inline-block and block in CSS?

Tags: css

What is the difference between `inline-block` and `block`?

And when should you use those values?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css_inline-block.asp) illustrates the difference pretty well.

The functional difference is that:

> Compared to `display: block`, the major difference is that `display: inline-block` does not add a line-break after the element, so the element can sit next to other elements.

You can think of the difference as that you want to use the behaviour of `block` elements inline, since normal `inline` elements don't allow such behaviours.

Answer (score -1):

The major difference is that **inline-block** does not add a line-break after the element, so the element can sit next to other elements in a line (as an inline element)

So additionally **inline-block** allows setting both width and height on the element. Inline elements don't allow set width and height.