# how to put my text in a single line in tailwinds?

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte

I want the result to be like this

[image]

but this is what i get

[image]

with my svelte code:

```html
<div
  style="background-image: url('{unsplash?.url}');"
  class="bg-black flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-cover"
>
  <Authenticate />

<!-- here is my div -->

  <div class="block flex absolute bottom-9 left-5 h-16 w-16">
    <img src={unsplash?.author.avatar} alt={unsplash?.author.username} class="rounded-full" />
    <p class="inline-block text-blank ml-2">
      By <a class="inline-block" target="__blank" href={unsplash?.author.url}
        >{unsplash?.author.username}</a
      >
    </p>
    <p class="inline-block text-black">
      Find similar pictures on <a class="inline-block" target="__blank" href="http://unsplash.com"
        >Unsplash</a
      >
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

i used inline-block, but doesn't work

Comment: `inline-block` has nothing to do with internal wrapping, though it enforces a box around the content. For an explanation what `inline-block` is about see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block). To prevent wrapping you need to set `white-space: nowrap` or similar; don't know what the respective Tailwind class for that is...

Comment: yeah, it worked, thanks. but i have a problem https://imgur.com/loJuRxo I want "Find similar pictures on Unsplash" this one below

Comment: Then don't use `inline-block` on the `p` elements, that puts the elements in text flow mode, `p` should stack on top of each other by default (they are block elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give more width  in parent div
from w-16 to w-[90%]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 8):

You probably want [Whitespace](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace) exactly `whitespace-nowrap` which is `white-space: nowrap;`
Although you may look at [Word break](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break) and [Text overflow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-overflow)