# How to put inline elements in a row?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make these elements inline in a row?

```
<h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3><h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
```

Right now, they appear one above the other. Can we arrange them to be next to each other on a row?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display:inline-block;` to the elements themselves:

`<h3 style="margin-left:8vh; display:inline-block;">`

Or you can use `flexbox`. With `flexbox`, wrap the two elements in a `div` and apply the inline styles on the `div`:

`<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; ">`

```html
<p>display:inline-block;</p>
<h3 style="margin-left:8vh; display:inline-block;">category</h3>
<h3 style="margin-left:8vh; display:inline-block;">category</h3>

<p>display:flex; flex-direction: row;</p>
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; ">
  <h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
  <h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
</div>

<p>display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end;</p>
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end;">
  <h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
  <h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
</div>

<p>display:flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-end;</p>
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction: row;justify-content: flex-end;">
  <h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
  <h3 style="margin-left:8vh">category</h3>
</div>
```