# I have a issue about the margin and display in my assignment

Tags: html, css

I am confused by the margin when I write the code:

```css
Section {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width="100%";
}

p1 {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-height: 1px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-left: 165px;
}

p2 {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-height: 1px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 165px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p class="p1"> Content 1 </p>
  <p class="p2"> Content 2 </p>
</section>
```

However, when I don't add the display, the background in section will not cover all the content. when I add the display: inline-block, it will cover but it will have the same first situation when I change `display:inline-block` to `display: inline` or `display:block`. So everyone can explain me what is happening please?

Comment: Read about elements display. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: `width="100%";` - that's not CSS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between display: inline and display: inline-block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969381/what-is-the-difference-between-display-inline-and-display-inline-block)

Comment: Your code is messy, CBroe already pointed out a wrong piece of code. Also `p1` and `p2` are invalid as well, should be `.p1` and `.p2` (class selector)

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow:auto or overflow:hidden or overflow:scroll.

```css
section {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto; // added
}
.p1 {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 165px;
}
.p2 {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 165px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p class="p1"> Content 1 </p>
  <p class="p2"> Content 2 </p>
</section>
```

Comment: `width: "100%"` this is **NOT** valid `CSS` ! This must be `width: 100%` (no quotes around the percentage value).

Comment: @ths you are right

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are invalid as well, should be `.p1` and `.p2`

Comment: yeah. I just copied it from the author

Answer (score 0):

The only issue is with you misused the double quotes in the width property of your section CSS, also the class selectors in your css haven't started with ".", so just update your css it will definately work.