# Queation related to DataTables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have the following code for the backend

```
$datatable->addColumn('product_quantity', function () {
    $quantities = TransactionSellLine::pluck('quantity')->all();
    return $quantities;
});
```

and I have the following code for the frontend

```
columns: [
    { data: 'product', name: 'product' },
    {
        data: 'product_quantity',
        "searchable": false,
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            if (type === 'display' && Array.isArray(data)) {
                var quantitiesHTML = '';
                data.forEach(function (quantity) {
                    quantitiesHTML += '<div>' + quantity + '</div>';
                });

                return quantitiesHTML;
            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    },
    { data: 'gross_profit', "searchable": false },
],
```

the quantities in product_quantity are shown in a single row but I want that to show one quantity in one row the second quantity in the second row, the third quantity in the third row and so on

I am sharing the output[image]
I am expecting that to show a single quantity in a single row

Answer (score 0):

On your `<table>` element, add the CSS classes `display` and `nowrap`, this force the text inside each cell to be on a single line.

Also, set the `scrollX` option on your DataTable to `true`, for example:

```
new DataTable('#example', {
    scrollX: true
});
```

Further information available at: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html

Answer (score 0):

You've specified that each quantity is in a separate `div`:

```
quantitiesHTML += '<div>' + quantity + '</div>';
```

By default, `div` is a block-level element, which means [it will expand to fill the container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8969381/6089612) - the table cell in this case - and force the next content below it.  If you don't want that, don't use `div`s.

You could have a comma-separated list by doing this instead:

```
render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
    if (type === 'display' && Array.isArray(data)) {
        return data.join(', ');
    } else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the product array too and show render them in a html.
The 'product' column should also has a rendering function that checks if the data is an array. If it is, it iterates through each product and builds an HTML string. This should display each product in a separate  element.

```
columns: [
    // Column for 'product'
    {
        data: 'product',
        name: 'product',
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            // Check if the data is an array and render accordingly
            if (type === 'display' && Array.isArray(data)) {
                var productsHTML = '';

                // Iterate through each product in the array and build HTML
                data.forEach(function (product) {
                    productsHTML += '<div>' + product + '</div>';
                });

                return productsHTML;  // Return the HTML string
            } else {
                return data;  // Return the original data if not an array
            }
        }
    },

    // Column for 'product_quantity'
    {
        data: 'product_quantity',
        "searchable": false,
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            // Check if the data is an array and render accordingly
            if (type === 'display' && Array.isArray(data)) {
                var quantitiesHTML = '';

                // Iterate through each quantity in the array and build HTML
                data.forEach(function (quantity) {
                    quantitiesHTML += '<div>' + quantity + '</div>';
                });

                return quantitiesHTML;  // Return the HTML string
            } else {
                return data;  // Return the original data if not an array
            }
        }
    },

    // Column for 'gross_profit'
    { data: 'gross_profit', "searchable": false },
],
```